# Remote was closed heroku and github connection error

Tags: git

I see on Heroku deployment:

Couldn't connect to GitHub Error: remote was closed,  authorization was denied, or an authentication message otherwise not received before the window closed.

How can I avoid the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the issue persists: there is an [incident currently in progress on GitHub](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/j597fw8kv04c)

> We are investigating reports of degraded performance and increased error rates

That could affect the ["Heroku GitHub Deploys" GitHub Integration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration)